# How to layer views

Tags: android

I have a custom-made view that extends the View class. I would like 2 instances of my custom view layered directly on top of each other. How should my layout file look to achieve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Turns out FrameLayout was what I wanted. Just do this in your layout:

```
    <FrameLayout  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.proj.MyView
            android:id="@+id/board1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.proj.MyView
            android:id="@+id/board2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I was going nuts about this and that seems to work quite well. I thought FrameLayout could only hold 1 visible child view at a time... I was already trying to create my own layout and was like thinking like: there's got to be an easier way!

P.S.
Oh and in case it's not obvious, the views are rendered from top to bottom by default so board2 gets drawn on top of board1.

Comment: Very nice. I have to say, I dislike how often relative layouts are used and am happy this one doesn't use one. (Relatives are just so messy! Every single object needs to have a few attributes describing its position! It seems like that defeats the purpose of using layouts...)

Answer (score 26):

Use a `RelativeLayout`. Later children of the `RelativeLayout` will overlap earlier children.

Answer (score 9):

While it's true that you can achieve layering using `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`, in API 21 and higher.. things have changed.

In API 21 and higher, the later children of xml doesn't mean it will overlap earlier children. Instead, it uses `Elevation` to determine which view will overlap other view (Z-Index).

For example, if you have something like this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The `View` will not be visible even though it was added after `Button`. That's because `Button` has higher elevation than `View`. To rearrange Z-Index you can add `elevation` attribute to respective views.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:elevation="0dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This way the `View` will overlap the `Button`.

More Information on
Elevation & Shadows: https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html