# Rendering the screen with notification and alert

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am showing notifications and on click of it i will show item details but before showing details i am showing password input alert then i have to show the details,i need to clear the background activity screen when alert appears,i have attached the image below,how to clear the background activity when alert appears ,i just need to show the data when password entered is valid else not or is there any other way to show alert on click of notification before showing item data ???

[image]

Comment: many solutions: Show another activity, instead of the detail, for the intent handling... Maybe add another layer to the activity layout and remove it after the password validation...

Comment: how to add other layer ?

Comment: lots of samples around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629940/how-to-layer-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) On the popup, you could set all the items in the xml to hidden

2) If the background is a website (genuinely cant tell), you could just hide that layout in the xml again

3) You could start a new activity on notification press with just the login screen on, then use the startActivityForResult to get the values

4) Create a frame layout above your xml, then hide/show that

Comment: I feel third point is much reliable to use has i have extras in my activity on click of notification

Comment: I am going to try it tomorrow ..,i am facing other issue ..,i will update here for sure

Comment: I have extras in say Scheduling service which i need to pass to IActivity class on click of notification,now if i introduce a new activity how will i retain those extras till IActivity? Can you show me with an example ?

Comment: but thanks the idea worked out :)  that is 4th point hide n show :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993675/sending-extras-on-clcik-of-notification-via-login  see this related ,i have to change the design again so