# Sending extras on clcik of notification via login

Tags: android

I have notification and on click of it ,i need to go to MainActivity Page to enter password and login and then go to ItemDetail Activity page.But while sending notification i have some extras which i need to pass to ItemDetail Activity page ,how will i send from on click to ItemActivity because i have MainActivity in between ?

```
private void sendNotification(String msg, int invM_id, int prmR_id) {

        try {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ItemActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        data1=WebService.InvoiceDetailForExeedDiscount1(invM_id);
***//I need these data in ItemActvity,i can read this before introducing MainActivity in between***
        notificationIntent.putExtra("invoiceList", data1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notified","yes");
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
               this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.invoice_alert))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);
            reminderStrings.append(prmR_id);
            reminderStrings.append(",");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        NOTIFICATION_ID++;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a double pass. You'll have to do it in two steps, e.g pass all the information to MainActivity, then maybe inside the MainActivity, on completion of that form check if there's that info, and if there is, pass it to ItemActivity

Comment: i'm afraid you have to start the other activity if you need information from it