# Text is not in front of image

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I would prefer a text to appear in front of my image, but instead I cant see the text

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_image_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cera_pro_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="Shop" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

### Output

[image]

As we see here, I dont see the text above the image and I dont know why

Comment: Take a look at these answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629940/how-to-layer-views Your elevation puts the image above the text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to layer views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629940/how-to-layer-views)

Comment: but the color white is because I have a black background, I'm specting to see the text above the black image not below

Comment: The layer order is determined by the elevation in this case. Your black background is drawn on top of the white text, so you won't see it.

Comment: I have used framelayouts and is not working

Comment: @TylerV , can you elaborate an answer ? thanks

Comment: wow i did not see the elevation, my god, thanks !

Comment: @CoffeeBreak, please remove the    android:elevation="10dp" line.. you will see the text in white color.

Comment: No, the solution in the answers there is to set elevation properly, or remove it (read all the answers, not just the top one, and try them before commenting that it doesn't work) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774058/9473786

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:elevation="10dp"` in `ImageView` tag

Answer (score 0):

make sure they both have the same elevation, all items with lesser elevation will be "Beneath" them.

By the way, instead of a frame layout I would have done a constraint layout and set them up relatively as you want.